# Generate dynamic xml file through jaxB

Tags: java, xml, struts2, jaxb

I want to generate this below mentioned xml file from my multiple action classes in struts2.

I perform multiple below mentioned operations from my Struts 2 action classes and adding them in single existing xml file.

1) Adding news in xml file
2) Adding footer info in xml file
3) Adding agency info in xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<agencylink>
    <agency>
        <title>Ministry of Games</title>
        <url>http://www.abc.gov.</url>
    </agency>

    <agencyNews>
        <date>22/Apr/2014</date>
        <news>How do I clear my web browsers cache, cookies, and history?</news>
    </agencyNews>
  <headerLogo>
    <img>images/header.jpg</img>
  </headerLogo>
  <footerText>
    <ftxt>All rights reserved.</ftxt>
  </footerText>
  <aLoginLogo>
    <img>images/logo1.jpg</img>
  </aLoginLogo>
  <aHeaderLogo>
    <img>images/logo2.jpg</img>
  </aHeaderLogo>

  </agencylink>
```

I am using JaxB.
When i am performing this different-different actions, my xml file is appended with that info but issue is tag name is same when it stored in xml file.

Tag name must be looks like above mentioned xml file.

When i update news information all tag name is changed as `<agencyNews>`.

So please any one help me to get this xml format through JaxB.

Its my Java Code below

---

```
    package com.ocr.nsw.xml;

    import java.util.List;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

    @XmlRootElement(name = "agencylink")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlSeeAlso({ Agency.class, AgencyNews.class, HeaderLogo.class,
            FooterText.class, ALoginLogo.class, AHeaderLogo.class })
    public class AgencyLink {

        @XmlElement(name = "agencyNews")
        private List<AgencyNews> adate;

        @XmlElement(name = "agencyNews")
        private List<AgencyNews> anews;

        @XmlElement(name = "agency")
        private List<Agency> atitle;

        @XmlElement(name = "agency")
        private List<Agency> aurl;

        @XmlElement(name = "footerText")
        private List<FooterText> aftxt;

        @XmlElement(name = "headerLogo")
        private List<HeaderLogo> headerLogoImg;

        @XmlElement(name = "aLoginLogo")
        private List<ALoginLogo> loginLogoImg;

        @XmlElement(name = "aHeaderLogo")
        private List<AHeaderLogo> aHeaderLogoImg;
    }

_____

public static void xmlWrite(List list, String filePath) {

    AgencyLink agencyLink = new AgencyLink();
    agencyLink.setAurl(null);
    agencyLink.setAnews(list);
    agencyLink.setAtitle(null);
    agencyLink.setAftxt(null);
    agencyLink.setHeaderLogoImg(null);
    agencyLink.setLoginLogoImg(null);
    agencyLink.setaHeaderLogoImg(null);

    if (marshalling(filePath, agencyLink)) {
        System.out.println("Success");
    }
}

------

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static Object unMarshalling(String filePath, Class clazz) {
    try {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Object obj = clazz.cast(jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file));
        return obj;
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

---

From this code i got this below mentioned XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<agencylink>
    <agencyNews xsi:type="agency" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <title>Ministry of Health</title>
        <url>http://www.abc.gov.bn</url>
    </agencyNews>
    <agencyNews>
        <date>22/Apr/2014</date>
        <news>How do I clear my web browsers cache, cookies, and history?</news>
    </agencyNews>
    <agencyNews>
        <date>20/10/2013</date>
        <news>10</news>
    </agencyNews>
    <agencyNews xsi:type="headerLogo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <img>images/header.jpg</img>
    </agencyNews>
    <agencyNews xsi:type="footerText" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ftxt>All rights reserved</ftxt>
    </agencyNews>
    <agencyNews xsi:type="aLoginLogo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <img>images/logo1.jpg</img>
    </agencyNews>
    <agencyNews xsi:type="aHeaderLogo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <img>images/logo2.jpg</img>
    </agencyNews>
</agencylink>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that your question is too difficult to understand. It lacks the necessary quality for readers to learn what your problem is, what data you are generating (by using JAXB) and where it differs from what you want to generate.

Comment: Show us your code and the associated annotations.

Comment: In my generated XML file all tag have same name like below from my above mentioned code
agencyLink.setAnews(list);
<agencyNews> ----- [xml file]

If i set agencyLink.setAurl(list); than my all xml tag is
<agency>

Comment: xsi:type="aHeaderLogo"
this should be tag name <aHeaderLogo>
but in my case tag name is <agencyNews>

Comment: What you are getting is correct based on how you've annotated your class. Your field possessing the annotation "aLogoHeader" is being set to `null` in your code, so it's not being marshalled to the proper tag. The list containing `AgencyNews` is being interpreted as potentially having several different types of news, one of which is "aHeaderLogo." The `xsi:type="aHeaderLogo"` is only specifying that the underlying content of the "agencyNews" tag will be of type "aHeaderLogo" as defined by your schema, not that the tag name itself should be different.